# What is difference between ">=" and "~=" when use in python "requirements.txt" for some library version?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

What is the difference between `>=` and `~=` when use in python *requirements.txt* for some library? For example `requests >= 2.18.0` and `requests ~= 2.18.0`

I have tried both the things and its working fine

```
requests >= 2.18.0
requests ~= 2.18.0
```

Could anyone please explain me the exact difference between the `>=` and `~=` operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To install **greater than or equal** to one version and **less** than another ([ordered comparisons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#inclusive-ordered-comparison)):

```sh
pip install 'SomeProject>=1,<2'
```

To install a version that’s **compatible** with a certain version ([compatible releases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release)):

```sh
pip install 'SomeProject~=1.4.2'
```

Both format specifiers are documented in [PEP 440 – Version Identification and Dependency Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).